# minimum in python without using min function [python 2.7]

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def minimum(x):
    mini = x[0]
    for i in x[0:]:
        if i < mini:
            mini = i
        else:
            mini = x[0]
    return (mini)
b = [1,2,3,4,5]
c= [3,6,2,7,9]
print minimum(b)
print minimum(c)
```

My code works for the first list (b) that I used to test (it returns 1 as the minimum), but for the second list (c) it returns (3) and I can't figure out why. Thanks!

:edit: Just figured it out, removing the "else" portion of the for loop fixed the problem

Comment: What was your reasoning behind that `else`?

Comment: Initially I had the for loop starting at x[1:] so I wanted to include x[0] as a potential candidate for the minimum. When I changed the for loop to include x[0] from the beginning I didn't remove the "else"

Comment: @stormageddon: but you *already* consider `x[0]` as a lowest value, because that is what you initialise `mini` to.

Comment: If you're having trouble with the logic of a short program like this one, this is a great tool. http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Comment: Also I thought that when you use if you had to attach an else to it to complete it. Thanks for all the feedback!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Min and Max of a List (without using min/max function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148491/min-and-max-of-a-list-without-using-min-max-function)

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `else` clause:

```
def minimum(x):
    mini = x[0]
    for i in x[0:]:
        if i < mini:
            mini = i
    return mini
```

You don't want to set the minimum back to the first value every time you find a value larger than the miminum found so far...

Without the `else`, you remember the lowest value found so far. There is no need to do anything else for values that are not lower.

Comment: Is this the definition of the built in `min()` function in  Python? Where can I find its original definition?

Comment: No, it is not. The built-in version is written in C, See the [source code of the builtins module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.4/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1520-L1652).

Comment: in C! So this is why usually is much faster than our functions defined using `while` or `for`?

Comment: Yes, there is no Python interpreter loop overhead.